# With js or jquery, how could I put an external css stylesheet from a page into a string, do something with it, then re-apply it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, stylesheet

With js or jquery, how could I put an external css stylesheet from a page into a string, do something with it, then re-apply it ?

I need the external css stylesheet as a string, not any of those computed applied style.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have no absolutely no idea why you would want to do that however you could use AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
  url : "path_to_css.css",
  type: "GET",
  success : function(data){
   console.log(data); //data is your string
  }
});
```

I am not quite sure how you would go about reapplying the stylesheet.

Or you could just manipulate the CSS of elements using JavaScript/JQuery like everyone else.

Comment: But jquery cannot get the style from the stylesheet, I tried $("myselector").css but it only get the computed and applied style from the stylesheet, which mean I can't get a percentage or know if it was applied as a percentage from it's stylesheet. I can't know either is for an example, a margin: 0 auto; as been applied to the body of the page...